# Adobe Air javascript imap ssl - unable to issue "list" command - bad unknown command

Tags: javascript, air, adobe, imap

I am writing an application in Adobe Air to fetch emails from Gmail. I am able to connect with SSL and successfully login, but then I'm unable to proceed further in fetching emails. I think this is because the SSL session is not maintained. Each time i issue a command, the session is lost.

To fetch email, I have to send a login request and then a `LIST "" "*"` command. But since the connection breaks after login, when i send that `LIST` command, it starts as a new connection and thinks I haven't logged in, and give the error message `a001 BAD Unknown command gf9if3619638pbc.89`

The code is below. Any idea to implement this, or is this even possible?

```
var socket;
function login() {
    socket = new air.SecureSocket();
    socket.connect('imap.gmail.com', 993);
    socket.writeUTFBytes("\n"+"a001 LOGIN username password");
    socket.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
}

function fetchEmail() {
    socket = new air.SecureSocket();
    socket.connect(server, port);
    socket.writeUTFBytes("\n"+'a001 LIST "" "*"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to SSL/TLS. Here, you're creating a new connection when you want to log and another new connection when you want to fetch the e-mails. As far as the server is concerned, these are two completely distinct connections. Removing these lines in `fetchEmail()` should be a start:

```
socket = new air.SecureSocket();
socket.connect(server, port);
```

In addition, you'll need to make sure you get the appropriate response code after the `LOGIN` command (or any other command in fact) before proceeding to the next command.

Comment: thanks for the response!. yes you are correct, i also tried that, by using the same socket object, but i am not getting any response.. i am able get proper response code for login alone and none of the other commands are working and i dont get any response further. this is working perfecly without SSL, but not working with SSL. i have the code at [link](testyourproject.com/sampl_ssl.html) .. line 74, is where its requesting for mailbox list.. any thoughts would be highly helpful.. thankyou!